# Google Firebase deploy gives - Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found

Tags: reactjs, firebase, deployment

I first created my React project with only frontend(client side) and deployed it on google firebase with ease. However, since my project contains making api calls, I learned that making api calls on the client-side is a big nono. So I created a backend express server to go with it. However, when I try to do firebase deploy, I am getting the "Error: HTTP Error: 404, Requested entity was not found."

Does google firebase allow users to deploy their website with a backend express server? Or do I have to look elsewhere to deploy my full-stack(front-end and backend) project?

firebase.json code

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "lol-finder-project",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Another thing I was thinking that maybe the issue is the alignment of my folders and public folders, maybe my root folder is out of place?
[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

1:  firebase login

2: firebase use --add ( Project ID)

3: firebase init (select hosting, than correct Project ID)

4: if needed (npm run build)

5: firebase deploy

Answer (score -2):

I solved the problem by installing `firebase-tools` again

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```